# Adjacency matrix and Bron–Kerbosch algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I want to find maximum cliques in a graph that is given to me in a form of adjacency matrix. I what I am trying to do I am being given the amount of shops I need to find with the same product tag that are being collected and whether sufficient amount of those shops was found

so input goes along lines 
x - shop count.
y - product count/tag.
z - in how many shops does the product need to be present.

so let's say I got

```
5 - x 
2 - y 
4 - z
Then the adjacency matrix going with it is:
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 2 2 1
1 2 0 2 2
1 2 2 0 1
1 1 2 1 0
```

There are two different products available, now I want to find out whether there are atleast 4 shops selling specific product. I found out about Bron–Kerbosch algorithm e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm
But I don't know how to pick my R, P and X subsets and how to represent them. It does not have to be very efficient nor I believe there is a need for any more advanced data structure than a 2D array but I just don't know how to use this adjacency matrix as a list of my vertices etc. Could anyone give me an idea on how to get started with this algorithm? Probably telling me how to treat R, P and X with my data would be sufficient. I would want to create my program in C++

Comment: That's not even an adjacency matrix... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: 1s and 2s stand for product tag, this means that they don't count as a member of the same clique even if the matrix might suggest so. As these are two different products we are taking about here.

Answer (score 0):

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm):

```
BronKerbosch3(G):
   P = V(G)
   R = X = empty
   for each vertex v in a degeneracy ordering of G:
       BronKerbosch2(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
       P := P \ {v}
       X := X ⋃ {v}
```

where `G` is the graph  and `BronKerbosch2()` is defined as :

```
BronKerbosch2(R,P,X):
   if P and X are both empty:
       report R as a maximal clique
   choose a pivot vertex u in P ⋃ X
   for each vertex v in P \ N(u):
       BronKerbosch2(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
       P := P \ {v}
       X := X ⋃ {v}
```

So now you know your choice of R, P and X. Also lookup what an adjacency matrix actually is as mentioned in the comments. Also, read the article carefully for the use of [degeneracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)) in the algorithm.

In C++, you could use `std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE>` for the 2D adjacency matrix and then proceed with the algorithm.